# Trouble mapping functions with the operator (/x)

Tags: function, haskell, mapping

So i have the result of a function that given a list of ints subtractes an int to all of the numbers in the list and then i want to divide the new list by x in this case 12. If i do the first paragraph of coding it gives me an error but if i do the second one it is possible. How do i do this and why does it give me an error?

```
let xs = [23,32,1,3]
map (/12) xs

map(/12) [23,32,1,3]

potenciasPor12 xs = map (/12) xs
```

This is the error i'm getting

```
<interactive>:176:1:
No instance for (Fractional Int)
  arising from a use of ‘potenciasPor12’
In the expression: potenciasPor12 xs
In an equation for ‘it’: it = potenciasPor12 xs
```

Comment: Hello Rui - welcome! A good idea is to also include the error message you're getting.

Comment: If you specified that `xs` is an `[Int]`, this is indeed not possible, since `(/)` is defined over `Fractional`.

Comment: Basically i have `potenciasPor12(funcao(xs))` in which `funcao` is basically `map (3-) xs` and i now have this error `<interactive>:176:1:
    No instance for (Fractional Int)
      arising from a use of ‘potenciasPor12’
    In the expression: potenciasPor12 xs
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = potenciasPor12 xs`

Comment: Sounds like the monomorphism restriction: `xs` is defaulting to `[Int]` instead of the more general `Num a => [a]`

Comment: The compiler is complaining about the type argument being provided to (/12), if you type `:t map (/12) xs` and `:t (/)` in ghci, it should tell you that your list is the problem. In this case since you're trying to map `(/12)` over a list of Ints, if you are not specifying the type of the list before hand then somehow the compiler's inference is defaulting the list from `Num a => [a]` to `[Int]`, in this case I'd just specify what types my list holds when creating the list, basically `let xs = [1,2,3,4...50] :: (Num a, Enum a) => [a]`

Comment: @MarkSeemann I think this is a fine MCVE. As it happens you won't be able to reproduce if you're on a newer version of GHCI (and can't tell that it's the monomorphism restriction), but we don't normally expect everyone to post their GHCI version as part of the question - it's quite reasonable to assume this would be the same for all Haskell versions, in which case the question appears to OP to contain everything needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @amalloy OK, I stand corrected. Thank you for clarifying that. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the monomorphism restriction is set (it is off by default in newer GCHi, but on in compiled code), then `xs` will default to `[Int]` rather than the more general type `Num a => [a]` which would work the the `(/)` operator.

(In GHCi 8.4.1, at least, it appears to default to `Integer` instead of `Int`.)

```
% ghci
GHCi, version 8.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> let xs = [1,2]
Prelude> :t xs
xs :: Num a => [a]
Prelude> :set -XMonomorphismRestriction
Prelude> let ys = [1,2]
Prelude> :t ys
ys :: [Integer]
```

Always provide explicit type signatures to be sure:

```
% ghci -XMonomorphismRestriction
GHCi, version 8.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> let xs = [23,32,1,3] :: Num a => [a]
Prelude> :t xs
xs :: Num a => [a]
Prelude> map (/12) xs
[1.9166666666666667,2.6666666666666665,8.333333333333333e-2,0.25]
```